# C# Masstransit how to handle exception when the queue is not available or down

Tags: c#-4.0, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using Masstransit with RabbitMQ to consume message from queue. Can anyone tell me how to handle exception when the queue is down or not available to get the message? following is my setup:

```
    var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(configManager.RabbitMqUrl), h =>
        {
            h.Username(configManager.RabbitMqUserName);
            h.Password(configManager.RabbitMqPassword);
        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RabbitMqConstants.Change, e =>
        {
            e.UseRetry(Retry.Immediate(configManager.ProcessorRetryNumber));
            e.Handler<ChangeDetected>(context =>
            {
                var task = Task.Run(() => consumer.Consume(context));
                return task;
            });
        });
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In our in-house RabbitMQ messaging implementation, we have approached/solved the publishing side of this (broker not available when want to publish) in two ways:

[1] We use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/) to asynchronously orchestrate a limited number of publishing retries (with delay between tries).  This overcomes situations where loss of connectivity to the broker is a minor network blip.

[2] If all publish retries fail, we use a 'message hospital' concept: we store enough detail about the failed-to-publish message to an alternative source (database; with additional failover to local file store), such that we can republish the failed messages later, if desired.  A variant on 'store and forward' (we can republish in bulk, but we also allow manual intervention to choose whether to republish).

All depends how important it is to you 'never to lose a message'.  Some redundancy of RabbitMQ brokers (clustering as Chris Patterson suggests or federation) is also an obvious step.  Clustering/federation gives you protection if you lose/want to do maintenance on one/some of your brokers.  The resilience strategies [1], [2] above give you protection if for some reason the message publisher can't see *any* RabbitMQ broker (for example network fault nearer the publisher).

Answer (score 2):

For receiving messages, MassTransit will automatically reconnect to the broker (RabbitMQ) when it comes back online. For sending messages, if your application is unable to connect to the broker to send, that's another problem entirely.

When using messaging in applications, it often becomes the single most important aspect of your infrastructure. So if you need high availability, then a cluster setup may be in your future (there are articles on clustering RabbitMQ out there).

MassTransit does not have any store-and-forward concepts in it, the broker needs to be available. While a few options have been discussed, nothing is concrete at this point nor generally available.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. But how could I force the Publish method to threw an Exception if the broker was down?

Answer (score 0):

After reading its documents, I realized that MassTransit just does not handle situations that the producer failed to send/publish to MQ or the consumer failed to send back the ACK.

So I have to go with another tool [CAP](https://github.com/dotnetcore/CAP), which implemented a local transaction table. You can put the send message action within the same local DB transaction of your business code. But the cons is that the CAP does not have saga implemented yet.

Otherwise, you have to implement a durable outbox pattern with the local transaction table by yourself.